# Unable compare two strings $time1 and $time2 with current time in 24 hr format in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Time in local host is 15:11:05. I want to compare two strings $time1 and $time2 with current time in 24 hr format in php . I have wriiten a code for it since time is 15:11:05 it needs to enter in if loop instead it is entering else loop

```
      function scheduleDate()
      {
       $time1 = '08:00:00';
       $time2 = '17:00:00';
       
       
       $t = date('H:i:s');
      dd($t);

      if ($time1 < $t && $t <$time2){
        
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(' + 1 hours'));
         return view('scheduleDate');

         
       
      }
      else
        return view('scheduleDate');

     }
```

Comment: $time1 = strtotime('08:00:00');
  $time2 = strtotime('17:00:00');
  $t = strtotime(date('H:i:s'));

if ($time1 < $t && $t <$time2){

 echo 1;
}else{

 echo 2;

}

Comment: I can't duplicate it - https://3v4l.org/ISVth . They both return true `(1)`, so it should enter the if loop. You can log the echo I provided with `Log::info()` before your if check to see what you're actually seeing.

Comment: Both the If and else statement return the same view, `$newDate` is not passed to the view.

Comment: I have done this , now it is working : $time1 = strtotime('08:00:00'); $time2 = strtotime('17:00:00'); $t = strtotime(date('H:i:s')); if ($time1 < $t && $t <$time2){ echo 1; }else{ echo 2; }

Answer (score 0):

Two **strings** cannot compare like this.
you can try like this ,

```
function scheduleDate()
  {
   $time1 = '08:00:00';
   $time2 = '17:00:00';
   $t = time();
  if (strtotime($time1) < $t && $t < strtotime($time2)){     
    $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(' + 1 hours'));
     return view('scheduleDate');      
  }
  else
    return view('scheduleDate');
 }
```